# Is it possible to have dynamic groupBy in Prometheus and Alertmanager?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

In my Prometheus alert configuration, I have some great `summary` annotations, containing different labels.

```
- alert: PodsPending
  expr: kube_pod_status_phase{phase="Pending"} > 0
  labels:
    severity: high
  annotations:
    summary: "Namespace {{$labels.namespace}} has pods stuck in Pending"
- alert: Failures
  expr: sum(application_responses_percent{status="500"}) by (environment, app, otherlabel) > 80
  for: 5m
  labels:
    severity: high
  annotations:
    summary: "({{$labels.environment}}) Too many errors in {{$labels.app}}"
```

In Alertmanager, I would like to group the alerts by these summaries. This way the set of labels to group by can be dynamic per alert since they are part of the summary.

However, since the `summary` is an annotation, it cannot be directly used in Alertmanagers `groupBy` configuration as it can only use labels. How can I use summary, or another dynamic way, for grouping alerts?

I've tried to check [metric-relabel-config](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#metric_relabel_configs) if the annotation could be transformed to a label, but there is no annotation data there.